# is it possible to display animated gif image in emulator Using phoneGap

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

im using phonegap frame work in android,my problem is animated gif image is not working in emulator.In browser it's working fine.my question is animated images are support to phonegap are not?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this on both a device and an emulator - and, good news, it works on the device, but doesn't in the emulator - only shows the first frame. Both are at 2.3.3, and this discussion (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3422) suggests that trying on 2.2 may solve the problem, so you can try that.

If you can afford it, I'd recomment testing on the device - it is much faster too, so makes life easier.