# jQuery Mobile + Phonegap :: Ajax "Loading" gif does not animate

Tags: android, jquery, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a working app built in jQuery Mobile and Phonegap (using Eclipse on Mac OSX)

Everything is working OK, except when the Ajax loading message pops up, the animated gif does not animate, it simply stick on the first frame.

Viewing the app in a web browser (as it is basically a mobile site) the gif animates no problem.

I have read that showing animated gifs on Android is tricky without using the web browser. Is there a way to get it to work? Maybe replace it with something in CSS3?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7426938/1321873

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't spot that one in the search results and related posts.

Comment: You are using the web browser in a phonegap app...

Comment: Can we see your code? My gifs animate fine in my phonegap app...

Comment: The thread Rajesh linked explains why it doesn't work. jQuery Mobile is HTML% and uses the webview, which does not animate animated gifs. Seems support was dropped a couple of years back and hasn't been put back in.

Answer (score 0):

Although the comments explain why it doesn't work, this might get you started on finding a workable replacement: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2767556/878602

Comment: Wicked, just trying to figure out how to add this into jQuery Mobile. Can't seem to target the loading widget to replace the contents with the <canvas> element :(